# Pymol - detecting collisions between rotating peptides

Tags: python, collision-detection, pymol

I have tripeptid(leu-lys-trp) opened in Pymol, and a script, that rotates peptides leu and trp around central peptide - lys.

```
from pymol import stored
from time import sleep

#select leu AA
cmd.select("LEU-sel","/leu///LEU")
#select trp AA
cmd.select("TRP","/leu///TRP")
#create selection of atom which i need to rotate around
cmd.select("TRPlys", "/leu///LYS`3/C")
xyz = cmd.get_model("TRPlys", 1).get_coord_list()

trp_con = []
cmd.iterate_state(1, "TRPlys","trp_con.append((x,y,z))")

print trp_con
i = 0
for i in range(0,100):
    cmd.rotate(xyz[0], 1, "TRP",0,1, None, trp_con[0])
    cmd.refresh()
    sleep(0.1)
```

I need to stop the rotation if there occur any collision between atoms of those peptides.

Is there any tool in pymol, that would make collision detection easier?

Comment: as far as I know there is no direct of doing so in Pymol, perhaps you can reverse engineer sculpt_vdw_vis_max but you probably need to check the distance of each atom and use its van der Waals radius.

Comment: I found cmd.overlap(unsupported function), that return > 0 if vdW are overlaping. I used that.